# Almost locality of cubic spline interpolation

Tags: reference-request, interpolation, approximation-theory, spline

The natural cubic interpolating spline is the unique $C^2$, interpolating cubic spline, endowed with two extra boundary conditions. Obtaining this spline, denoted by $s(x)$, involves the inversion of a 5-diagonal matrix, and can therefore be shown to be *nonlocal*, i.e., every interpolation point $(x,f(x_i) )$ affects $s(x)$ at *every* point $x$. See [here](http://levien.com/phd/LevienSequinCAD09_014.pdf) for example.

**My questions:** Is there any result indicating that the natural cubic spline is *almost non-local*, i.e., that as $|x_i - x|$ grows, the effect of $f(x_i)$ on $s(x)$ vanishes?

**Remarks:**

1. The non-interpolating B-splines approximation can easily be local, but I am interested in the *interpolating* spline.
2. Numerics indicate that, in practice, the natural cubic spline is almost local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_i$ be the unique cubic spline such that $S_i(i) = 1$ and $S_i(j) = 0$ for $i \ne j$. These are sometimes called "cardinal splines". Obviously any cubic spline with breaks at the integers can be written as a linear combination of the $S_i$.

The "almost local" property follows from the fact that $S_i(x)$ decays exponentially as $|x-i|$ increases. There is a discussion [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9e69/2f7f370e496d355de6653c62e26bebaf1bec.pdf), but you can probably find more modern treatments, too.

Presumably, there is some connection with the fact that elements of the inverse of a banded matrix decay exponentially. Reference [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1984-43-168/S0025-5718-1984-0758197-9/).

Comment: You gave your answer less credit then it deserves - The De-Boor paper you referenced to gives exactly that. Thanks